# How can I limit Docker to only run one container at a time?

Tags: docker

I want set up docker so that it can only run one container at a time. That is, at any time, at most one container can be running.

Comment: I would assume this type of setting would be in the docker daemon itself, which doesn't seem to list such an option: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/ . Of course you can write a bash script to enforce this. Also don't you need to define some requirements for this? Like what do you want to happen if someone runs a container while one is already running? Do you want to close the previous one and run the new one or keep the old one and ignore the new one?

Comment: if you are looking this over cloud, like AWS then it possible but for local system then you need some script like @Perplexabot mentioned

Answer (score 0):

we can lock limit on container,limit memory and cpu same
check before running containers
docker ps (-q) or docker stop(docker ps -a -q)
run specific docker container

memory limit- docker run -d -p 80 --memory="296mb" myimage